# User variables defined in hook_variable_info() in rules

Tags: rules, tokens

I'm declaring the varialbes of a custom module in [hook_variable_info()](http://api.drupalhelp.net/api/variable/variable.api.php/function/hook_variable_info/7). Now I'd like to access some of them in rules. How can I do that?

The reason for this is that the [Variable](http://drupal.org/project/variable) module gives me the chance to added fine grained access control for this values. Otherwise I would be forced to give users full access to administer rules.

Update: I found this issue: [Make Drupal variables accessible with data browser in rules](http://drupal.org/node/1434826)
To be honest I don't fully understand what it is saying.

Answer (score 2):

As the Rules module uses tokens, and the Variable module implements [hook_tokens()](http://api.drupalhelp.net/api/variable/variable.tokens.inc/function/variable_tokens/7), you should not do anything.

If the value returned from that implementation of `hook_tokens()` is not the value you would expect, in a module of yours you could implement [hook_tokens_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_tokens_alter/7) to alter the token values returned by the Variable module.

Reading [Entity property information](http://drupal.org/node/1021466), I get fago means code similar to the following one should be used.

```
function mymodule_entity_property_info() {
  $info = array();

  // Add meta-data about the variables exposed from the Variable module.
  $properties = &$info['site']['properties'];

  // ...

  return $info;
}
```

I didn't find any information about the parameters passed, for example, to the setter callback, even though [entity_property_verbatim_set()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!includes!entity.property.inc/function/entity_property_verbatim_set/7) is defined as `entity_property_verbatim_set(&$data, $name, $value, $langcode, $type, $info)`.

```
function entity_property_verbatim_set(&$data, $name, $value, $langcode, $type, $info) {
  $name = isset($info['schema field']) ? $info['schema field'] : $name;
  if (is_array($data) || (is_object($data) && $data instanceof ArrayAccess)) {
    $data[$name] = $value;
  }
  elseif (is_object($data)) {
    $data->$name = $value;
  }
}
```

Vice versa, [entity_metadata_user_set_properties()](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/entity_metadata_user_set_properties/7) is defined as `entity_metadata_user_set_properties($account, $name, $value)`.

```
function entity_metadata_user_set_properties($account, $name, $value) {
  switch ($name) {
    case 'roles':
      $account->roles = array_intersect_key(user_roles(), array_flip($value));
      break;
  }
}
```

[entity_metadata_user_entity_property_info()](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/entity_metadata_user_entity_property_info/7) uses that setter callback in the following definition.

```
  $properties['roles'] = array(
    'label' => t("User roles"), 
    'description' => t("The roles of the user."), 
    'type' => 'list<integer>', 
    'getter callback' => 'entity_metadata_user_get_properties', 
    'setter callback' => 'entity_metadata_user_set_properties', 
    'setter permission' => 'administer users', 
    'options list' => 'entity_metadata_user_roles', 
    'access callback' => 'entity_metadata_user_properties_access',
  );
```

Comment: That's waht I expected. But it doesn't work. I can see a lot of variables at admin/config/system/variable but none of them is available in rules.

Comment: Thanks for all the additional information! Unfortunately I'm still not sure how to move on though. Let's see whether I get a helping hand from fago or someone else how knows more about entity properties.

Comment: Did you find a satisfying solution now?